# Responsive Bootstrap navbar - menu button for smartphones not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with dropdown menu. Now I want to make it usable for smartphone users too. I have the bootstrap classes already included, so I thought I could use bootstrap.

I used a [generato](http://bootstrapdesigntools.com/tools/bootstrap-menu-builder/)r for creating me a basic navbar, just to test if it's working.

Here's the result: https://jsfiddle.net/bwbuqco2/

When you resize the window in the fiddle, a menu button for smaller screens will appear. But on my site it doesn't. The navbar just disappears completely on my site and I don't know why.

I deactivated any stylings for my old navbar, but that didnt fix the problem.

If you need any further information, let me know. I have no clue where the problem is.

I would also be open for solutions beside bootstrap.

Here's my navbar structure:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container" style="margin-left:100px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            Startseite
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="ueber-mich/">
                            Über&nbsp;mich
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#anker">
                            Referenzen
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="link1/">link1/</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link2/">link2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link3/">link3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link4/">link4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link4/">link4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link5/">link5</a></li>                 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link6/">
                            link6
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav>-->
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
margin-left: -3px;
margin-bottom: 0;
background: @color-purple;
border: none;
.navbar-nav{
> li {

    > ul {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        display: none;
        z-index: 1;
        background: rgba(41, 38, 87, 0.7);
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-left: -50px;

        >li{

            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
    > a {
        border: 1px solid @color-purple;
        display: block;
        padding: 1em;
        color: @color-white;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
        >a:hover{
            background: @color-purple;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: @color-white;
            }

        }
    }

    > a {
        color: @color-white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 25px 40px 25px 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
        >a:hover{
            color: @color-white;
            text-decoration: underline;
            }
}

>li:hover{

    > ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: visible;
    }

}

}
}
```

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the jQuery, bootstrap CSS and JS files linked correctly.
You are missing a lot of whats needed.
Please visiting https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar.

I put a working example using part of your code here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBMEyZ

"a menu button for smaller screens will appear. But on my site it doesn't. "
You are missing the hamburger button, among other things.

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

Keep in mind I didn't use any extra CSS, just the bootstrap file.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
           <a href="">
           Startseite
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="ueber-mich/">
           Über&nbsp;mich
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#anker">
           Referenzen
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="link1/">link1/</a></li>
              <li><a href="link2/">link2</a></li>
              <li><a href="link3/">link3</a></li>
              <li><a href="link4/">link4</a></li>
              <li><a href="link4/">link4</a></li>
              <li><a href="link5/">link5</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="link6/">
           link6
           </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
     </ul>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```